Script to populate team vacation calendar has error "You need to have writer access to this calendar.. Skipping."
I am troubleshooting our version of this Google App Script to populate a team vacation calendar  (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar). Since the original product manager left and the script got transferred to me, the execution keeps running into the same error. It detects an out of office event, begins to import it to the team vacation calendar, but then this happens

Error attempting to import event: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed with error: You need to have writer access to this calendar.. Skipping.

shows the events attempting to import, and the error message

I'm not sure which calendar it doesn't have writer access to, or which account needs writer access. I'm the owner of the Apps Script project, and I think it should have access to see, edit, share, and permanently delete all the calendars I can access (see first screenshot)
Project OAuth Scopes -- 3 scopes requested -- See, edit, share, and permanently delete all the calendars you can access using Google Calendar

I have permissions 'Make changes and manage sharing' for our team vacation calendar.
I've run into this error for out of office events on my calendar, and one other person's calendar (who happens to be the admin of our GSuite).
Mysteriously, the script was able to import an out of office event from the calendar of another member of our org (who is not a Gsuite admin).
The previous owner of this script had more Gsuite admin permissions than I do. Is there a specific permission I could try that could fix this?
// Set the ID of the team calendar to add events to
let TEAM_CALENDAR_ID = '[omitted from mre]';
// Set the email address of the Google Group that contains everyone in the team.
// Ensure the group has less than 500 members to avoid timeouts.
// Change to an array in order to add indirect members from multiple groups, for example:
// let GROUP_EMAIL = ['ENTER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE', 'ENTER_ANOTHER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE'];
let GROUP_EMAIL = 'ommited from mre';

let EXCLUDE_EMAILS = ['ommited from mre'];

let ONLY_DIRECT_MEMBERS = false;

let EVENT_TYPES = ['outOfOffice'];

let MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE = 3;

/**
 * Sets up the script to run automatically every hour.
 */
function setup() {
  let triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if (triggers.length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Triggers are already setup.');
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sync').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  // Runs the first sync immediately.
  sync();
}

/**
 * Looks through the group members' public calendars and adds 
 * out of office' events to the team calendar.
 */
function sync() {
  // Defines the calendar event date range to search.
  let today = new Date();
  let startDate = new Date();
  startDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 30); // Set start date to 30 days ago
  let maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE);

  // Determines the time the the script was last run.
  let lastRun = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRun');
  lastRun = lastRun ? new Date(lastRun) : null;

  // Gets the list of users in the Google Group.
  let users = getAllMembers(GROUP_EMAIL);
  if (ONLY_DIRECT_MEMBERS){
    users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();
  } else if (Array.isArray(GROUP_EMAIL)) {
    users = getUsersFromGroups(GROUP_EMAIL);
  }

  //Filter out excluded emails
  users = users.filter(function(user) {
  return!EXCLUDE_EMAILS.includes(user.getEmail());
  });

  // For each user, finds events having the specified event types in the event
  // summary in the specified date range. Imports each of those to the team
  // calendar.
  let count = 0;
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    let username = user.getEmail().split('@')[0];
    Logger.log(username); // DEBUG
    EVENT_TYPES.forEach(function(eventType) {
      let events = findEvents(user, eventType, startDate, maxDate, lastRun);
      Logger.log(events); // DEBUG
      events.forEach(function(event) {
        importEvent(username, event);
        count++;
      }); // End foreach event.
    }); // End foreach eventType.
  }); // End foreach user.

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastRun', today);
  console.log('Imported ' + count + ' events');
}

/**
 * Imports the given event from the user's calendar into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {string} username The team member that is attending the event.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event to import.
 */
function importEvent(username, event) {
  event.summary = '[' + username + '] ' + event.summary;
  event.organizer = {
    id: TEAM_CALENDAR_ID,
  };
  event.attendees = [];

  // If the event is not of type 'default', it can't be imported, so it needs
  // to be changed.
  if (event.eventType != 'default') {
    event.eventType = 'default';
    delete event.outOfOfficeProperties;
    delete event.focusTimeProperties;
  }

  console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
  try {
    Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error attempting to import event: %s. Skipping.',
        e.toString());
  }
}

/**
 * In a given user's calendar, looks for events of the given type
 * within the specified date range and returns any such events found.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user to retrieve events for.
 * @param {string} eventType The event type to look for.
 * @param {Date} start The starting date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} end The ending date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} optSince A date indicating the last time this script was run.
 * @return {Calendar.Event[]} An array of calendar events.
 */
function findEvents(user, eventType, start, end, optSince) {
  let params = {
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  if (optSince) {
    // This prevents the script from examining events that have not been
    // modified since the specified date (that is, the last time the
    // script was run).
    params.updatedMin = formatDateAsRFC3339(optSince);
  }
  let pageToken = null;
  let events = [];
  do {
    params.pageToken = pageToken;
    let response;
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, eventType, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
    events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.eventType === eventType && shouldImportEvent(user, item);
    }));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return events;
}

/**
 * Determines if the given event should be imported into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user that is attending the event.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event being considered.
 * @return {boolean} True if the event should be imported.
 */
function shouldImportEvent(user, event) {
  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}

/**
 * Returns an RFC3339 formated date String corresponding to the given
 * Date object.
 * @param {Date} date a Date.
 * @return {string} a formatted date string.
 */
function formatDateAsRFC3339(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZ');
}

/**
* Get both direct and indirect members (and delete duplicates).
* @param {string} the e-mail address of the group.
* @return {object} direct and indirect members.
*/
function getAllMembers(groupEmail) {
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var childGroups = group.getGroups();
  for (var i = 0; i < childGroups.length; i++) {
    var childGroup = childGroups[i];
    users = users.concat(getAllMembers(childGroup.getEmail()));
  }
  // Remove duplicate members
  var uniqueUsers = [];
  var userEmails = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (!userEmails[user.getEmail()]) {
      uniqueUsers.push(user);
      userEmails[user.getEmail()] = true;
    }
  }
  return uniqueUsers;
}

/**
* Get indirect members from multiple groups (and delete duplicates).
* @param {array} the e-mail addresses of multiple groups.
* @return {object} indirect members of multiple groups.
*/
function getUsersFromGroups(groupEmails) {
  let users = [];
  for (let groupEmail of groupEmails) {
    let groupUsers = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail).getUsers();
    for (let user of groupUsers) {
      if (!users.some(u => u.getEmail() === user.getEmail())) {
        users.push(user);
      }
    }
  }
  return users;
}


Welcome to stackoverflow! May I ask if there's another Super Admin in your organization? I believe that if the code is working before, the problem is not on your script but on your permission/access level.

How is the script run? Have you been able to review the project triggers? Have you tried to execute the script using the Debug button from the Apps Script editor?

The error is in your code (Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);). The account running the script (you) does not have write access to TEAM_CALENDAR_ID. This is probably because you did not create this calendar. You need to have the calendar's owner, share the calendar with your account minimally to "Make changes to events".

@DazWilkin, I have permissions 'Make changes and manage sharing' for the calendar in question

@JatsPPG I'm interested in hearing more! Is there a specific privilege I could be granted? The other Super Admin is reluctant to give me full Super Admin privileges (to keep the # of Super Admin to a minimum)

@Wicket the script execution is time-driven (once per hour). The trigger works, it starts running every hour. But once it finds an event, it tries to import it, and gives the error message "Error attempting to import event: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed with error: You need to have writer access to this calendar.. Skipping."

I see. I believe that you need to be a Super Admin to your organization to be able to make the script work OR ask the Super Admin directly to run the script if there is no permission provided to you.
